# セレクト要素への３点リーダー

Tags: android, css, html5

ご質問失礼いたします。
テキストなどがある要素の横幅に収まらない場合、下記のように書くことで改行を禁止し、３点リーダー（...）を最後に持たせる事ができるかと想うのですが

```
p {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

これをセレクト要素のオプション要素（各項目）にもたせられたらと思っております。Android端末からセレクト要素をセレクトするさいに改行されているのを３点リーダーにしたいのですが、どうもセレクト要素に反映させるのは困難なようでして、しかも端末ごとにセレクトする際のUIというんですかね、そちらも異なるのでそもそもできるのかなと言ったところなのですが、、
なにか手がかりなど些細なことでも構いませんのでアドバイスなどいただけたらと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/113707

Answer (score 1):

「option要素にtext-overflowを適用できるか」という質問に対しての答えは「不可能」です。

[text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)の適用対象は[ブロックレベル要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)であり、[option要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)はブロックレベル要素ではないからです。

代替の手段はあると思うので、別の質問を立てられるのが良いかと。

Comment: htbさま ご回答ありがとうございます。こちらの質問、放置状態になっており本当に申し訳ございませんでした。option要素とtext-overflowの関係性について的確なご回答ありがとうございます。的確なご回答のおかげ別の方法での対応検討に少しでも早く着手し自己解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 回答の承認ができます。ご検討ください。